# Word like "ancestors" or "ancestry line" which includes the initial subject?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to give a proper name to a function in a programme. What the function does is to return the node on which it is called, and also its ancestry line until the top node. The concept can be applied to family trees as well...

Let's say:

```
A
- B
- C
  - D
  - E
    - F
```

If this was called on the node F, it would return the following nodes: F, E, C, B and A.

My understanding is that ancestry/ancestors excludes the node itself, i.e. in the example the ancestry of F would be E, C, B and A.

Comment: If you show the [ancestry of Henry VIII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_VIII_of_England#Ancestry) on Wikipedia (click on "show" on the right), it includes Henry as the child of his parents.

Comment: Why don't you call your function something like "getAncestorsAndSelf"? It is self explanatory and I have seen it worded that way before to refer to this kind of function and even if it is not a single word, this may make it easier to understand for whoever reads the code later...

Comment: Also, depending on the context and the application, tree nodes may, or may not be considered to be their own ancestors, so I wouldn't take it for granted.

Comment: @SamuelVimes, I think I will go for your solution, thanks. It is an ugly name, but there is no doubt about what it does. FWIW, for me as a spanish speaker, somebody's ancestry does not include mr somebody.

Comment: @ikaros45 you are welcome :). I agree that the name is not very nice, but when coding I think it is better to aim for clarity and to avoid ambiguities. I will post it as an answer, in case someone else finds this helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your function something like "getAncestorsAndSelf". I have seen it worded that way before to refer to this kind of function and while it is not a single word, it is self explanatory and may make it easier to understand for whoever reads the code later.

Also, depending on the context and the application, tree nodes may, or may not be considered to be their own ancestors, so it shouldn't be taken for granted that the ancestry includes the node itself.